# Is there a media-handling module that can handle midi files?

Tags: 7, media

I've been using [MP3 Player](https://drupal.org/project/mp3player) to provide an on-page mp3 player, but I also need to be able to handle midi files. Right now the best I can do is allow them to be uploaded into the "mp3 file" field, but when it renders the node, it just gives a link to the file, which mean you have to navigate to the file (or open it in a new tab) for the browser to play it.

Answer (score 3):

MIDI files can be embedded straight into the page with the `<object>` tag, so there should be some way to then output that with the link that views gives you at the moment. If you went with a separate field then it's be easy enough to do with Views output rewriting.

After a quick look for a flash solution, it seems that flash itself doesn't have any support for MIDI, so a flash based player is unlikely.

Comment: On top of this, you could simply write a Custom Formatter (http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) to output the FileField you use for your MIDI files with the <object> tag or any other HTML wrapper you'd like to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want a module to do this, you can look at the [Audio module](http://drupal.org/project/audio). However, this module is currently said to be "unstable", even though over 3000 sites report having it installed. So with that many users it might be worth taking a look at anyways. The author also has an alternative suggestion using FileField and SWF Tools modules.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module in conjunction with either [MediaElement](http://drupal.org/project/mediaelement) or the [MediaFront](http://drupal.org/project/mediafront) module to handle MP3 files.